# How to Send Bytes Message to JMS Queue via Jmeter JMS point to point

Tags: jmeter, byte

I want to send my request XML in BytesFormat to my request queue via jmeter. How to achieve that?.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into underlying [JMSSampler class source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_0/src/protocol/jms/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/jms/sampler/JMSSampler.java) it is not possible to send a [BytesMessage](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/BytesMessage.html) using [JMS Point-to-Point](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Point-to-Point) sampler, you will either have to go for

- [JMS Publisher](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Publisher) sampler which is capable of sending an [ObjectMessage](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/ObjectMessage.html)
- or implement your own Message sending logic using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) language.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a tool like [JMSToolBox](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox/wiki) where you can automate the sending of ByteMessages based on message templates

(I'm biaised, I'm the author of JMSToolBox)